# Typescript export * with a nested alias

Tags: typescript

Basically, I want to do something like:

```
export * as services.* from "./services";
```

A workaround is:

```
import * as _services from "./services";
export const services = _services;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Doesn't look like this is possible, it isn't covered in [the mdn export docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently now way to handle wildcard exports rather than module loaders. Basically you will have an index file in services folder which exports the services individually:

```
export * from './services.service1';
export * from './services.service2';
export * from './services.service3';
```

And then you can import everything from index:

```
import { * } from './services';
```

BTW: it is not a best practice and is encouraged not to use.

Look at [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2726).